# Requirement on data distribution when using certain data mining classifiers

Tags: distributions, data-mining, weka

I am a little bit confused on whether data mining classifiers make any assumptions about the distribution of the data.
I myself have a computer science background, but when I have discussions with an economist, he asks whether these classifiers do not make any assumptions of the distribution of the data (e.g. normal distribution).

As far as I know, you can make a distinction between parametric and non-parametric classifiers in which the first is based on the statistical probability distribution of each class and the non-parametric classifier is used in case of an unknown density function.
When I look at [this paper](http://www.mecs-press.org/ijitcs/ijitcs-v4-n7/IJITCS-V4-N7-6.pdf) I find some classifiers being parametric (Bayes, Decision Trees, SVM) and some being non-parametric (Multilayer Perceptron).
(Oddly enough, [this paper](http://www.ise.bgu.ac.il/faculty/liorr/hbchap9.pdf) claims that decision trees are non-parametric.)

However, [here](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Normal-distribution-td810.html) I find that it is not necessary to test whether the data is normally distributed when using data mining tools.

Do the data mining classifiers (esspecially in WEKA) require the input features and the feature that will be predicted to follow a certain distribution?
If so, do you know some references on which classifiers (J48,Naive Bayes, SVM,Random Forest, Multilayer Perceptron etc.) require which distribution?
If not, why isn't this necessary?